# Set default image cropper program in android

Tags: android, default, crop

In my application the user selects an image. When the CROP_IMAGE intent is launched it displays the dialog to select one of the available image croppers installed on the device. I would like to solve that one of the installed programs launch default that user don't have to choose all time which program wants to use.

Is it possible to skip this chooser dialog and launch one image cropper automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer :

```
Intent cropApps = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropApps.setType("image/*");
List<ResolveInfo> list = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(cropApps, 0);
int size = list.size();
if (size == 0) 
{           
    Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
} 
else 
{
    ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent();
    cropIntent.setClassName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name);
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 800);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 800);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
}
```

Comment: You should mark your own answer as solution to the described problem.